# Remove every word after hitting an integer in a list of strings (including the number)

Tags: python, arrays, string

The following is a subset of a list I'm having trouble with:

```
array(['DORFLEX 10 CP AV CH', 'CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA 5MG 30 CP EMS GEN C',
       'ADVIL MULHER 400MG AVULSO', 'SPIDUFEN MENTA 600MG C/10 SACHES L',
       'PONSTAN 500MG 8X3 CP', 'TANDRILAX 30 CP',
       'PARACETAMOL 750MG 20 CP NEOQ GEN',
       'DICLOFENACO SOD 50MG 20 CP MEDL GEN C','DORFLEX 30CP',
       'BENLYSTA 200MG/ML SOL INJ 4 SER PRE 1ML GELAD'], dtype=object)
```

The problem is that, for example, the first element of the list: "DORFLEX 10 ..." (and many other names) appear repeatedly in the list with the same name, but the number that follows it is different (different sizes), for example, "DORFLEX 15 ...". I'm trying to leave only the word "DORFLEX". Dropping the string after a space would solve this specific problem, but I have a lot of compound names like "DICLOFENAC SOD 50MG ...". That's why I'm wanting to drop the entire string after reaching the number (including the number) in order to reduce the number of products that are repeated but appear in different sizes.

So far I haven't found anything that brings me close to that. Any help is welcome.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Why is this tagged with `pandas`? Can you provide an expected output for your sample input?

Comment: sorry, this list of strings is in a column of a pandas dataframe. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use forward look-up (regex):

```py
re.search('.*?(?=( \d)|$)', some_string).group()
```

Or apply this to the entire list:

```py
[re.search('.*?(?=( \d)|$)', line).group() for line in lines]
```

Then you get all your names in one go:

```
['DORFLEX',
 'CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA',
 'ADVIL MULHER',
 'SPIDUFEN MENTA',
 'PONSTAN',
 'TANDRILAX',
 'PARACETAMOL',
 'DICLOFENACO SOD',
 'DORFLEX',
 'BENLYSTA']
```

Comment: using `search` this way is risky, it will fail if you have a string without number ;) `[re.search('(\D*)\s?', line).group() for line in lines]` would be better.

Comment: If you also want to accept strings without numbers you could use a pattern like `'.+?(?=( \d)|$)'`. You could also just do `'\D*'` but it would have a hanging space

Comment: `'.*?(?=( \d)|$)'` if you don't want to fail on empty string. This is why I like `re.split` for such things, it's less prone to unforeseen no-match errors ;)

Comment: as always, we could do a lot of different things, it all really boils down to the exact spec of the consumer, what input they expect and what they can assume to never get etc. anyway, I think both our solutions are valid so I'm upvoting yours :)

Comment: sure, likewise ;)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would use a numpy array, but you could use a regex to split on the first digit (if any).

Taking a list as example here:

```
l =   ['DORFLEX 10 CP AV CH', 'CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA 5MG 30 CP EMS GEN C',
       'ADVIL MULHER 400MG AVULSO', 'SPIDUFEN MENTA 600MG C/10 SACHES L',
       'PONSTAN 500MG 8X3 CP', 'TANDRILAX 30 CP',
       'PARACETAMOL 750MG 20 CP NEOQ GEN',
       'DICLOFENACO SOD 50MG 20 CP MEDL GEN C','DORFLEX 30CP',
       'BENLYSTA 200MG/ML SOL INJ 4 SER PRE 1ML GELAD']

import re

out = [re.split('\s?\d', s, maxsplit=1)[0] for s in l]
```

or using `re.search`:

```
out = [re.search('(\D*)\s?', line).group() for line in l]
```

output:

```
['DORFLEX', 'CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA', 'ADVIL MULHER', 'SPIDUFEN MENTA', 'PONSTAN',
 'TANDRILAX', 'PARACETAMOL', 'DICLOFENACO SOD', 'DORFLEX', 'BENLYSTA']
```

If really you have a numpy array `a`, this is the same logic:

```
out = np.array([re.split('\s?\d', s, maxsplit=1)[0] for s in a])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
input_list = [
    'DORFLEX 10 CP AV CH',
    'CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA 5MG 30 CP EMS GEN C',
    'ADVIL MULHER 400MG AVULSO',
    'SPIDUFEN MENTA 600MG C/10 SACHES L',
    'PONSTAN 500MG 8X3 CP', 
    'TANDRILAX 30 CP',
    'PARACETAMOL 750MG 20 CP NEOQ GEN',
    'DICLOFENACO SOD 50MG 20 CP MEDL GEN C',
    'DORFLEX 30CP',
    'BENLYSTA 200MG/ML SOL INJ 4 SER PRE 1ML GELAD'
]
output_list = []

for element in input_list:
    for index, char in enumerate(element):
        if char.isnumeric():
            output_list.append(element[:index])
            break

print(output_list)
# output:
# ['DORFLEX ',
#  'CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA ',
#  'ADVIL MULHER ',
#  'SPIDUFEN MENTA ',
#  'PONSTAN ',
#  'TANDRILAX ',
#  'PARACETAMOL ',
#  'DICLOFENACO SOD ',
#  'DORFLEX ',
#  'BENLYSTA ']
```

We basically iterate over the `element`s of `input_list`, then over the indices and characters of each `element`. Once we hit a numerical character, we slice the `element` up to that index and append it to an `output_list`. We then break from the inner for loop in order to move on to the next `element` immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Out of curiosity, I decided to compare the performance of various methods. I used this code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import annotations
import re
from timeit import timeit

l = [
    "DORFLEX 10 CP AV CH",
    "CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA 5MG 30 CP EMS GEN C",
    "ADVIL MULHER 400MG AVULSO",
    "SPIDUFEN MENTA 600MG C/10 SACHES L",
    "PONSTAN 500MG 8X3 CP",
    "TANDRILAX 30 CP",
    "PARACETAMOL 750MG 20 CP NEOQ GEN",
    "DICLOFENACO SOD 50MG 20 CP MEDL GEN C",
    "DORFLEX 30CP",
    "BENLYSTA 200MG/ML SOL INJ 4 SER PRE 1ML GELAD",
]

PROG = re.compile(".*?(?=( \d)|$)")


def with_compiled_regex(l: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    return [PROG.search(x).group() for x in l]


def with_regex(l: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    return [re.search(".*?(?=( \d)|$)", x).group() for x in l]


def without(l: list[str]) -> list[str]:
    updated = []
    for item in l:
        new = []
        for sub in item.split(" "):
            if sub[0].isnumeric():
                break
            new.append(sub)
        updated.append(" ".join(new))
    return updated


print(timeit("with_regex(l)", globals=globals(), number=10000))
print(timeit("with_compiled_regex(l)", globals=globals(), number=10000))
print(timeit("without(l)", globals=globals(), number=10000))
```

This provides very consistent results near:

```
0.130591894
0.07869331399999999
0.07071069099999999
```

As you can see, without regex as probably expected is faster... but not by much *if* it is compiled. Therefore, if you intend to do this much, you'd benefit by either not using regex or compiling your search.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers seem to remove all numeric values from your name strings, or use regex.

Here is a more pythonic alternative:

```
def extractName(fullStr):
   spltName = fullStr.split(' ')
   newSpltName = []
   for subStr in spltName:
      if not subStr.isdigit()
         newSpltName.append(subStr)
      else:
         break
   return ' '.join(newSpltName)

new_l = map(extractName, l)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel this is more "pythonic"; that is pretty subjective. Nevertheless, it doesn't fully work. Even if you add the missing `:` on the `if` line, it doesn't filter the results correctly. For example, `CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA 5MG 30 CP EMS GEN C` becomes `CLOR.CICLOBENZAPRINA 5MG`.

Comment: "More pythonic" is indeed subjective and probably depends on how I learned Python. I just find that regex expressions are far from the code readability mantra of Python. As for keeping the 5MG (and the such), it was on purpose as I thought it was what was asked (only removing integers when they were alone). But I might have been wrong on that point

Comment: I see. Could be that I misunderstood.